# Using Lubridate in R Studio to create year, month, day columns gives unexpected results

Tags: r, lubridate

I am importing a csv file with dates in and using lubridate to create additional columns to show the year, month and day. The date column in the csv file is called "Date". My code is as below:

```
library (lubridate)
Dates<-  read.csv("DateSpreadsheet.csv")
Dates$Year<- year(Dates$Date)
Dates$Month<- month(Dates$Date)
Dates$Day<-day(Dates$Date)
View (Dates)
```

The problem is that in the table produced the year column shows the day and the day column shows the first 2 digits of the year.

[Table showing columns for date, year, month and day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XDLf.jpg)

I would be grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the date is not stored in the ymd format. You can use the following code yo update your date table and it will give you the correct output.

```
Dates$Date<-dmy(Dates$Date)
```

let me know if this works.